Does Kafka 2.5.1 supports TLSv1.3 with Java 8 or it needs Java 11 only for this
Just have a query. So, i am running Kafka image with Kafka 2.5.1 on top of Java 8 version that does support TLS 1.3.
Need to know if Kafka 2.5.1 supports TLS 1.3 with Java 8 or does it need Java 11 only to work?
If Kafka can indeed enable TLSv1.3 with Java 8, then what all changes do i need to do in Kafka configuration to make it work.
